# My keyboard keeps waking up the computer even when everything is disabled in /proc/acpi/wakeup . How can I stop it from doing this?

Tags: keyboard, suspend

I don't know what else can I do to stop this behaviour. I want to suspend the laptop and just wake it up when I press the power button.

wakeup settings:

> ```
> Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node  
> P0P1      S4    *disabled  
> GLAN      S4    *disabled  
> EHC1      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0  
> EHC2      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1a.0  
> XHC   S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.0  
> HDEF      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0  
> RP01      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0  
> PXSX      S4    *disabled  
> RP02      S4    *disabled  
> PXSX      S4    *disabled  
> RP03      S5    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.2  
> PXSX      S5    *disabled  pci:0000:03:00.0  
>         *disabled  platform:rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0  
>         *disabled  platform:rtsx_pci_ms.0   
> RP04      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.3   
> PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:04:00.0  
> RP05      S4    *disabled  
> PXSX      S4    *disabled  
> RP06      S4    *disabled  
> PXSX      S4    *disabled  
> RP07      S4    *disabled  
> PXSX      S4    *disabled  
> RP08      S4    *disabled  
> PXSX      S4    *disabled  
> PEG0      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:01.0  
> PEGP      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:01:00.0  
> PEG1      S4    *disabled  
> PEGP      S4    *disabled  
> PEG2      S4    *disabled  
> PEG3      S4    *disabled  
> LID0      S3    *disabled  platform:PNP0C0D:00  
> SLPB      S3    *disabled  platform:PNP0C0E:00
> ```

My laptop is an Acer Aspire V5-571G and there isn't any option in the firmware to switch this.

I'm using 4.4 kernel and elementaryOS Loki. However this happened with other distros like Arch and Ubuntu.